# why use JSON.Parse(data) after ajax sucess?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have this following code.

```
success: function(data) { 
    console.log(data) //everything
    console.log(data['quote']); //undefined
    var JSONObject = JSON.parse(data); //why parse again?
    var quote =JSONObject['quote']
    console.log(data['quote']); //returns quote
    }
```

why do I need to parse the JSON object again even though the return from api call is already a JSON Object?

Comment: To parse `string` JSON to `JavaScript` object which could read using `JavaScript`

Comment: You can set `dataType: 'json'` instead

Comment: Your terminology is wrong. There isn't a JSON _object_, just JSON which is a string. And as Arun says, if you include that property in your AJAX call, jQuery will automatically parse the data for you.

Comment: From http://www.json.org/ [...] JSON is a text format that is completely language independent [...]. Keyword here being "text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the data returned from server is JSON string instead JSON object. If the data is string, you need to parse that string to javascript object.